# Using usleep to perform action every second

Tags: php, time

I have that pseudo crone scheduler implemented in PHP. The heart of the project is a simple while loop acting like this:

```
while((time()-$start)<$time_limit) {
  //Perform jobs
     ...
  //Sleep a second
  sleep(1)
}
```

Now obviously, if the job part takes some significant amount of time, like 0.5 seconds, sooner of later one second might be skipped. Here I assume it will always be less than a second.

Just for you to imagine:

```
Timeline:
 +0    0  
 +0.4  0.4 - execution
 +1    1.4 - sleep
 +0.3  1.7 - execution
 +1    2.7 - sleep
 +0.6  3.3 - execution
```

So, I decided to make a smarter sleep algorithm. My idea was taking current micro-second time and seeking how much micro seconds do I have to sleep to the next second:

```
  /*Sleep exactly to the next whole second*/
  //Get current microtime as xxxxx.yyyyy (so the whole part is seconds)
  $utime = microtime(true);
  //Get the next whole second by rounding this up
  $utime_next = ceil($utime);
  //Find some 0.xxx of time that makes the difference 
  //this+exec time of the scripts in this iteration should be 1
  $diff = $utime_next-$utime;
  //Sleep for that ammount of usecs
  usleep($diff*1000000);
  //Log for debug
  $this->log("Slept for $diff seconds.");
```

Now the results seem to be very disturbing. While in the past, the log had some seconds missing:

> [2.3.2014    **2:13:08**] -> INFO:       >> include 'script.php';
> [2.3.2014    **2:13:10**] -> INFO:       >> include 'script.php';
> [2.3.2014    2:13:11] -> INFO:       >> include 'script.php';

The new version with usleep seems to ignore mathematics, which is much worse:

> [2.3.2014    2:44:**54**] -> INFO:     Slept for **0.67506289482117** seconds.
> [2.3.2014    2:44:**54**] -> INFO:       >> include 'script.php';
> [2.3.2014    2:44:**54**] -> INFO:     Slept for **0.67906403541565** seconds.
> [2.3.2014    2:44:**54**] -> INFO:       >> include 'script.php';

So what the hell? My calculator confirms that just the sleep time is `0.67506289482117+0.67906403541565 = 1.35412693023682`. I'm using [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to generate dates in the log.

<sub>**Note:** This is a fun project. No need to explain why this is a bad idea.</sub>

Comment: It's working fine for me: http://pastebin.com/51Jkb15c takes ~20 seconds to execute.

Comment: Strange... There must be something I have overlooked then. That makes this question useless.

Comment: Could be your date is wrong. Maybe you're not updating it for every iteration.